# Static route is ignored

Tags: windows, routing

I am trying to add a static route with no success and would appreciate your help

I am using the following command:

```
route -P add 172.29.16.34 mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 IF 7
```

the problem is, the rule is ignored, and it uses the default gateway.
What am I missing?

those are the interfaces and routing table:

[image]

[image]

Thanks.